# How to create Report from DB information in PDF format without using jasper

Tags: java, report

I want to create reports in PDF using the data available in database. I want to do some data manipulation and use the charts and details to be shown in pdf to the user.Suppose say there are 2 columns in DB a and b . I want to show in the PDF, the value of a and b and the addition of a and b. What i can use to generate this pdf report?

I thought of using jasper, but i donot want to use it. Instead is there any other logic in java that can help to solve this problem. Please suggest with examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Birt](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) is a tool that can be used to generate all sorts of reports. There are plugins for Eclipse that you can use to help you get going and you can definitely add logic in Java. It can output your report in multiple formats including PDF, HTML, and I believe even Word docs.

If you've used Eclipse before you should be able to figure out the basics, but it can get as complicated as you want. In its simplest form you attach data sources (such as a database with a JDBC connection) and you structure your joins and layout fields onto a form. You can even tie it into a Java EE container if needed.

There are examples on their website and it has a rather large community to help with questions.

Comment: I dont know, is there any other way like without using any external tool??

Comment: By external tool do you mean Eclipse or BIRT? You can certainly design BIRT reports without Eclipse but it would be a lot harder. If you don't want to use a tool like BIRT you are going to have to do a lot of things by hand, but it can be done. At the least you are likely going to have use some libraries to help you create the PDFs.

I've used [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) to make PDFs before and it isn't too hard to use. It certainly isn't going to be one stop shopping like BIRT would be though. 

I've also used [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to create PDFs, but that is advanced.

Comment: By external tool i meant BIRT. Anyway i will be using eclipse, but let me try BIRT then, i am not sure how hard/easy will that be. Thanks for the information.